# Magento 2: Difficulty in add simple product, product get added as virtual product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

HI I am trying to add product in **magento 2** from the admin panel. But product is added as the virtual product even if I select the **simple** product when adding new product.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is occurs because the simple product you have added it has no weight. you have choosen **This item has no weight** option from **Weight attribute**.

> Please check Weight attribute of **Simple Product**. Make sure you
>   selected  **The item has  weight** option. You can leave **Weight field blank** if you dont ' want to add weight. You must need to select option **The item has weight.**

[image]

Clear the cache by runnning **cache:clean** commmand and check.

Answer (score 3):

Go to admin `Products -> Catalog` add product from upper right corner there is dropdown click on **simple product** as show in below image

[image]

Add weight greater than 0 and select This item has weight and save product.

[image]